# Desktop App - Login de usuarios - usuario de base o usuario de servidor

Tags: mysql, login

MySQL y Java.

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que tiene la clásica ventana de login, la cual pide usuario y contraseña para poder acceder.

Ya he realizado ventanas de login con la forma clásica de: escribir el usuario y contraseña, consultar a la base y permitir o denegar acceso.

Ahora se me ha ocurrido que:

- Crear un usuario en el servidor (no dentro de la base) con nombre y contraseña.
- Utilizar ese usuario de servidor y contraseña para ser evaluado en la ventana de login.
- Si el nombre del usuario y la contraseña coinciden: Realizar la conexión y dar acceso..en caso contrario, no dar acceso.

Obviamente al usuario creado, se le quitarían todos los permisos administrador y solo se le daría acceso a una base de datos.

La idea de todo esto, es por que me gustaría que el dashboard de MySQL Workbench me dijera exactamente que usuario está conectado y cuanto lleva conectado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es esto viable, alguien lo ha intentado?

No tengo problemas con los métodos de conexión.

Comment: Parece una pregunta basada en opiniones.

Comment: Así se hacía habitualmente en Oracle para trabajar con el viejo Forms&Reports. Tiene implicaciones como controlar el dueño de los objetos (las tablas, los SP, etc) para garantizar seguridad, hacer auditoría a nivel de BD, etc. De ser viable, seguro lo es. ¿Has probado algo de esta aproximación en lo que podamos ayudarte?

Comment: lo raro, es que no deberias tener nunca ningun usuario conectado... y los tiempos de conexion son los que tardenlos querys...

Comment: Dependiendo de la aplicación, en mi caso las conexiones las hago con una Connection Factory. Me saldría del tema si les cuento como administro la conexiones.